# Looping through Word documents in a folder

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have written a code which loops through all word documents in a folder. I am getting an error 'Object Required'. What I am trying to do here is: I have 200 word files in a folder containing same types of table. I want to open one file, import all the tables of that file into one sheet of excel and then from that sheet, copy particular cells to another sheet. These should be done in loop for all the word files. I am new to programming. Please provide your inputs to resolve this. Thanks.

```
Sub DoVBRoutineNow()
Dim file
Dim path As String


path = "D:\Ujjivan\CAM to MIS\CAM Unsecured\CAM\"

file = Dir(path & "*.docx")
Do While file <> ""
Documents.Open Filename:=path & file

Call ImportWordTable

ActiveDocument.Save
ActiveDocument.Close

file = Dir()
Loop
End Sub

Sub ImportWordTable()

Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim tableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel
Dim resultRow As Long
Dim tableStart As Integer
Dim tableTot As Integer

On Error Resume Next

ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").ClearContents

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
tableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
tableTot = wdDoc.tables.Count
If tableNo = 0 Then
    MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
    vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
    'tableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & tableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
    "Enter the table to start from", "Import Word Table", "1")
    tableNo = 1
End If

resultRow = 4
 For tableStart = 1 To tableTot
    With .tables(tableStart)
        'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
        For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
            For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                Cells(resultRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
            Next iCol
            resultRow = resultRow + 1
        Next iRow
    End With
    resultRow = resultRow + 1
Next tableStart
End With

'Call simpleXlsMerger

End Sub


Sub simpleXlsMerger()
'Dim bookList As Workbook
'Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As 
Object
Dim n As Integer
n = 3
Dim oFound, pFound As Range
Dim oLookin As Range
Dim sLookFor, tLookFor As String

sLookFor = "Loan amount (Rs)"
Set oLookin = Worksheets("Tables").UsedRange
Set oFound = oLookin.Find(what:=sLookFor, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, 
MatchCase:=False)
Worksheets("Tables").Cells(oFound.Row + 1, oFound.Column).Copy
If Not oFound Is Nothing Then
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(n, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'MsgBox oLookin.Range("A" & oFound.Row).Value
End If

n = n + 1
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Activate
'bookList.Close savechanges:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: Error at this line: Documents.Open Filename:=path & file

Comment: Where are you running this code?  In Word?

Comment: No. I am running it in excel.

Comment: Excel doesn't have a `Documents` - that is a Word collection.  You need to provide more information about what you're doing here.  Also the code for `ImportWordTable`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please help me with it further? What I am trying to do here is, I have 200 Word documents having same kind of tables. I want to import these tables of one word file into one sheet of a excel file and perform some action on that data. And then continue the loop for all word files of that folder.

Comment: Maybe start here:  https://www.universalclass.com/articles/computers/automating-word-functions-with-excel-vba-code.htm

Comment: @TimWilliams: Thanks a lot. It was a huge help. The issue is solved.